# .htaccess: RewriteCond works for xy.com/?id=12, but not for xy.com/index.php/?id=12

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to password-protect a page with a given id somewhere in the query string. My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=12
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=protected_uri:1]

Order Deny,Allow

AuthName "Protected"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /blabla/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /
Require valid-user

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=protected_uri
Satisfy any
```

This works fine for http://xy.com/?id=12, but it doesn't work for http://xy.com/index.php?id=12. For the second URL no password is needed.

I have no idea why this isn's working, because id=12 in the RewriteCond-Line should match all the URL's with id=12 in it?

Thanks for your help!
Ben

Comment: Try using `RewriteRule (.*) - [E=protected_uri:1]`. Are there any other rewriteRules?

Comment: Still the same result. No, there aren't any other rewrite-rules in my .htaccess-file. But maybe my provider has the ability to add some other rules which i can not see?

Comment: Try adding `Deny from REDIRECT_protected_uri`

Comment: Hmm, didn't work either...the same problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have an additional comment: it does only work for root, but nor for all other URL's like http://xy.com/blabla.php?id=12.

Comment: `Order Deny,Allow` should be `Order Allow,Deny`. Otherwise Allow from all would override Deny from ...

Comment: Still no effect. I think it has something to do on how the server internally rewrites index.php to / (or vice-versa). Anyway, thank you for your help, Gerben!